# iOS: How to reduce image size for splashscreen

Tags: ios, splash-screen

For a universal app to support iphones and ipads, there are several resolutions, retina or non-retina screen, portrait and landscape orientation, so that there would be many *.png, this will hugely increase the final size of app bundle size.

Is there any good advice for reduce image sizes?

Comment: Also note you can use .jpg images but it'll cost you a very slight loading time increase to decompress the jpg.

Comment: @Shizam, Can I use .jpg? Because Apple says 'All launch images must be PNG files and must reside in the top level of your app’s bundle directory. (Avoid using interlaced PNGs '

Comment: I've used .jpg files as recently as 6 months ago, we switched back to .png files because our bundle size constraints loosened up.  If you do use .jpgs you have to explicitly call out their names (with .jpg) in the info.plist, you can't rely on just calling them Default.jpg.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Imageoptim](http://imageoptim.com/), which can optimize also png and jpeg images.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use a .jpg as a splash.

Just remember to change the `UILaunchImageFile = "splash.jpg"` setting in the **info.plist** file.

I'm using it in my latest app. A 700K png is only a 180k jpg.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `pngcrush`. You can use it to try all possible encoding methods and get the smallest files possible.

Comment: Imageoptim also tries quite a number of different compression algorithms.